# how to gradually grow an object in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am new in unity a im currently working on a game in which i want to scale my player gradually till certain value. Please help me out.
this is my growing scale

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerGrowth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timer = 0f;
    public float growTime = 6f;
    public float maxSize = 2f;

    public bool isMaxSize = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (isMaxSize == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Grow());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Grow()
    {
        Vector3 startScale = transform.localScale;
        Vector3 maxScale = new Vector3(maxSize, maxSize);

        do 
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, maxScale, timer / growTime);
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        while (timer < growTime);
        {
            isMaxSize = true;
        }
    }


}
```

While using this my player scale very awkwardly
[image]

Comment: you havent scaled on all 3 planes.. so yes.. it will scale a little weird.

Comment: Sorry but how can i do that ?

Comment: well you said new new Vector3(maxSize, maxSize); you need 3 sizes for 3 part vector...

Comment: To make things simple just use `Vector3.one * maxSize` in such cases

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this in update function will work

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float targetScale = 2.0f; // The final scale you want to achieve
    public float scaleSpeed = 0.5f; // The speed at which the player scales

    private Vector3 initialScale; // The initial scale of the player
    private bool isScaling = false; // Flag to control scaling

    void Start()
    {
        initialScale = transform.localScale; // Store the initial scale
        StartScaling(); // Call a method to start the scaling process
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isScaling)
        {
            // Gradually scale the player towards the target scale
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, initialScale * targetScale, scaleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Check if the difference between current scale and target scale is small
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.localScale, initialScale * targetScale) < 0.01f)
            {
                transform.localScale = initialScale * targetScale; // Set exact target scale
                isScaling = false; // Stop scaling
            }
        }
    }

    void StartScaling()
    {
        isScaling = true; // Set flag to start scaling
    }
}
```